# Having issues with making Sprites transparent in pygame! (image included inside)

Tags: python, image, transparency, pygame

[image: Doubt]

Even though I've set the transparency of the image to 'True', I am still unable to clear the fuzz around it. I've tried various methods, playing around with it in Photoshop to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like on the image in photoshop, you'll need to clean up the file. Check the alpha on the parts of the image that are white.

Comment: Thanks. I visited a #pygame channel, turns out jpgs are not too pygame friendly. Also, the white has to be cleared out. Which can be done easily by using GIMP or Photoshop. Thanks for answering though!

Answer (score 0):

Note: save as png.
Jpeg will cause compression, probably why you are expecting a solid color of white, and it isn't.

Png will be loss-less, and even has alpha-transparency (255 levels if wanted).

Or you can set alpha using color_key of white.